# make update with 2 where clauses

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make update function with 2 where clauses, this is my model code :

```
function updateJawabanSensus($where,$where1,$data) {
   $this->db->where('id_jawaban',$where); 
   $this->db->where('id_sensus',$where1); 
   $this->db->update($this->_table, $data); 
   return $this->db->affected_rows(); 
}
```

controller code :

```
function update_jawaban_sensus() {  

    $id_jawaban = $this->input->post('id_jawaban', TRUE);
    $id_sensus = $this->input->post('id_sensus', TRUE);
    $id_keluarga = $this->input->post('id_keluarga', TRUE);
    $id_pertanyaan_sensus = $this->input->post('id_pertanyaan_sensus', TRUE);
    $jawaban = $this->input->post('jawab_0', TRUE);
    $id_indikator = $this->input->post('idInd_0', TRUE);
    $indikator = $this->input->post('indikator_0');
    $bobot = $this->m_pilihan_jawaban->get_bobot($id_sensus,$jawaban);
    $nilai_bobot = $bobot * $indikator;
        $data = array(
                'id_jawaban' => $id_jawaban,
                'id_sensus' => $id_sensus,
                'id_indikator' => $id_indikator,
                'id_keluarga' => $id_keluarga,
                'id_pertanyaan_sensus' => $id_pertanyaan_sensus,
                'jawaban' => $jawaban,
                'nilai_bobot' => $nilai_bobot
            );
        //echo json_encode($jawaban);
      $result = $this->m_jawaban_sensus->updateJawabanSensus(array('id_jawaban' => $id_jawaban,'id_sensus' => $id_sensus), $data);
     redirect('indikatorkesejahteraan/c_jawaban_sensus/konfirmasi/'.$id_sensus.'/'.$id_keluarga);
}
```

but when i click the update button the data can't change..thanks for your attention

Comment: at what point in your code (in model) are you setting `$this->_table` ?

Comment: You must use one `where` combined with `and`

Comment: In your controller, you are not sending the parameters your model method needs.

Comment: i declare like this bro : $this->_table='tbl_jawaban_sensus';

Comment: You need to show that in your code. Edit your initial question and add that piece of code where it belongs. Also, im not your bro.

Comment: Check your parameter number in controller and model

Comment: so what can i do in my controller? @CodeGodie

Comment: $result = $this->m_jawaban_sensus->updateJawabanSensus($id_jawaban,$id_sensus, $data);

Comment: thanks for your help @NanaPartykar it work's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem: you are not showing where `$this->_table` is defined in your model. (I will assume you are setting this in your `__construct`)

Second problem: your model method expects three parameters:  `updateJawabanSensus($where,$where1,$data)`, but you are only sending two:

```
updateJawabanSensus(array('id_jawaban' => $id_jawaban,'id_sensus' => $id_sensus), $data);
```

**Solution**

Codeigniter will accept multiple where clauses in an array. Since you already have an array, just send it once, and permit your model method to accept only two parameters.

Controller:

```
$arr = array(
         'id_jawaban' => $id_jawaban,
         'id_sensus' => $id_sensus
       );
$this->m_jawaban_sensus->updateJawabanSensus($arr, $data);
```

Model:

```
function updateJawabanSensus($where,$data) {
   $this->db->where($where); 
   $this->db->update($this->_table, $data); 
   return $this->db->affected_rows(); 
}
```

*Source*: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Answer (score 1):

You are sending only parameter form you controller.

```
$result = $this->m_jawaban_sensus->updateJawabanSensus(array('id_jawaban' => $id_jawaban,'id_sensus' => $id_sensus), $data);
```

Instead you using two where condition you can simply do in once.

**Model**

```
function updateJawabanSensus($where,$data) {
   $this->db->where($where); 
   $this->db->update($this->_table, $data); 
   return $this->db->affected_rows(); 
}
```